# Can I replace 3/4 particle board underlayment with 1/2 OSB?

Tags: flooring, subfloor, underlayment, particle-board, osb

I ripped up carpet to replace with LVP in my 1976 bi-level home to find 3/4 particle board on top of the subfloor. I then found out that the particle board should be removed.

I spoke with a friend who does renovations and such for a living and he informed me that I could instead use 1/2 OSB to replace the 3/4 stuff.

Underneath the particle board is plywood which I assume is just the subfloor. Not sure how thick it is though.

Any issues with that?

Comment: *"I then found out that the particle board should be removed."* Why - is it in bad shape? Or did you just get an opinion from someone that hates particle board? I mean, **I** hate particle board, But I won't rip it out simply because it's particle board if it's not displaying problems... If the surface is smooth, flat enough, etc. there's not much point in ripping it out.

Comment: I agree, and you haven't told us what's underneath it. We can't answer with half the story.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want 3/4" OSB?

Comment: If the concern is VOCs/offgassing, you'll get more of that from new OSB than from old particle board that spent the last 50 years getting rid of its volatiles.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Everywhere I look online 9/10 people say to replace mainly for the water swelling issues.  There are quite a few spots where water or something went through the carpet and caused swelling. Other than that, most of the boards look fine but I've only torn up like 25% of the carpet so far.

Comment: @Huesmann No reason at all. My friend called me today because I asked if he had a supplier he uses so I can get the OSB a bit cheaper and he informed me that I could use 1/2 instead. Took a look online and it is pretty significant cost savings if 1/2 is a viable option.

Comment: Still waiting to hear what's underneath. The question isn't answerable without that information. Please revise your question with all relevant information from these comments. It doesn't belong down here. Take the [tour].

Comment: Take the [tour] and look through [how to ask a good question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better feel for the place. It's quite normal once you get used to it.

Comment: FYI: 1/2" OSB is actually usually 15/32" or 7/16". Your 70s era particle board is _probably_ actually 3/4". That means this new area will be 9/32" to 5/16 lower than whatever rooms it adjoins. You'll probably want to make up that (nominal) 1/4" somehow. Adding the extra layer of whatever material you choose may cost nearly as much as buying 3/4" material in the first place.

Comment: Well, it isn't really about _this site_ but basic communication. Find out how thick the first layer is. Find or drill a hole, or look for stamps on the underside. Again, the question isn't answerable....